# Use NSString in different file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two files(`file1.m` and `file2.m`) and two strings(`NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello!"]` in file1.m and NSString *str2 in file2.m).I set str2 = str1 by a method and then the str2's value is "hello!".

Then I change the `str2` to `"hello hello!"` in `file2.m`,and i want the `str1` in `file1.m` is also changed to `"hello hello!"`.

How to do?
If you konw,please tell me.

Thank you!

Comment: accept some answers first

Answer (score 3):

How would you do the same thing in C, or Java, or most any other language?  While the syntax differs, the general concepts of using a global variable, a function, or class methods does not.

In short, it appears you need some more study and just providing some code wouldn't do much to help.

Comment: In C，I use char＊。I can use NSMutableArray＊ in different files，but cann't use NSString ＊。

Comment: If you called a method to set str2 = str1, why wouldn't have to call a method to set str1 = str2?  Equals is an assignment operator - it's not bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

properties. when one changes, change the other.

Comment: Thank you!When I change the str2 to "hello hello!" in file2.m,But the str1 in file1.m isn't changed to "hello hello!".Why?

Comment: use some glue code. make a setter called setStr2:(NSString *)newValue and in it set str1.